# Which is the preferred way to clear a std::string object?

Tags: c++, memory-management, resources, c++17, idioms

```
#include <string>

using namespace std::literals;

int main()
{
    auto str = std::string{};
    str.resize(1024);

    // #1
    str = {};

    // #2
    str = ""; 

    // #3
    str = ""s;

    // #4
    str.clear();
    
    // #5
    str.resize(0);
    str.shrink_to_fit();
}
```

**Which is the preferred way to clear a** `std::string` **object? And Why?**

Comment: Do these statement result in different assembly code emitted for each? Did you check that 1st?

Comment: `shrink_to_fit` is a bit different in that it removes any unused capacity. Apparently, `clear` can do that too, but most implementations don't: _"Unlike for `std::vector::clear`, the C++ standard does not explicitly require that capacity is unchanged by this function, but existing implementations do not change capacity. This means that they do not release the allocated memory."_ ([cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/clear))

Comment: See this video: [string.clear() vs string = ""](https://youtu.be/3X9qK7HWxjk)

Comment: I believe this context requires "What do you want to do after clearing it" to be complete. Or any way does its work should be okay.

Comment: I mean, if there is a function literally called `clear`, you'd think that's the preferred way to *clear* a string...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer to your question

> Which is the preferred way to clear a std::string object?

(and you knew this before asking), is #4, `str.clear();`, since this **clear**s the string.

- #1 is initialization
- #2 and #3 are assignments
- #4, the **answer**, clears the string
- #5 resizes the string

You can copy and paste your code into godbolt and check the assembler output, if you are interested in other insights.

The idiomatic correct anser is #4 and maybe #1

Comment: #1 is also an assignment

Comment: Yes, you are right

Comment: #1 is **not** initialization. It is assignment.

Comment: Yes, and also you are right. Ayxan Haqverdili has already written that. Why doubling the comment?

Comment: @ArminMontigny because your answer says "#1 is initialization" and that's wrong. It's just assignment. That's what I meant as well.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want from the code and what style you like mostly.

For all intents and purposes `#1` and `#2` behave the same - just assign empty data without changing `capacity()`.

The `#3` constructs new string and immidiatelly move-assigns it to the old one. This one changes not only `size()` but also `capacity()`. Version `#5` does the same but does not require constructing new `std::string`.

And lastly `#4` changes the size and MIGHT change capacity but this is implementation dependant.